# SimpleXML returns combined XML content

Tags: php, xml

I have following code

public function returnArrayOfXmlElements(string $xml_path, string $element_key)
        {

```
        // Variables
        $this->simplexml_array    = (array)$this->returnSimpleXmlObject($xml_path);

        // Variables With Dependencies
        $this->xml_elements       = $this->simplexml_array[$element_key];

        foreach ($this->xml_elements as $this->array_key => $this->array_value) {

            $this->xml_elements_rectified[] = (array)$this->array_value;

        }

        return $this->xml_elements_rectified;

    }
```

When I try this,

```
switch ($menu_name) {

            case 'secondary':

                    // Variables
                    $this->menu_directory    = constant('ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY_FRONTEND_MENU_SECONDARY');
                    $this->request_uri       = (empty($_GET['request']) !== TRUE ? $_GET['request'] : constant('SETTING_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT'));

                    // Variables With Dependencies
                    $this->section_name      = strtolower(substr($this->request_uri, 0, strpos($this->request_uri, '/')));
                    $this->menu_file         = $this->section_name.'.xml';
                    $this->menu_data         = $this->library_xml->returnArrayOfXmlElements($this->menu_directory.$this->menu_file, 'item');

                    echo '
                        <ul menu-secondary>
                            <li class="icon"><icon id="section-'.$this->section_name.'"></icon></li>
                    ';

                        foreach ($this->menu_data as $this->array_key => $this->menu_information) {

                            // Variables
                            $this->item_hook    = $this->menu_information['hook'];
                            $this->item_name    = $this->menu_information['name'];

                            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->item_hook.'">'.$this->item_name.'</a></li>';

                        }

                    echo '
                        </ul>
                    ';

                break;

            default:

                    // Variables
                    $this->menu_directory      = constant('ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY_FRONTEND_MENU');
                    $this->menu_file           = 'main.xml';

                    // Variables With Dependencies
                    $this->menu_data           = $this->library_xml->returnArrayOfXmlElements($this->menu_directory.$this->menu_file, 'item');

                    echo '
                        <ul menu-main>
                            <li>polybotes</li>
                    ';

                        foreach ($this->menu_data as $this->array_key => $this->menu_information) {

                            // Variables
                            $this->item_hook    = $this->menu_information['hook'];
                            $this->item_name    = $this->menu_information['name'];

                            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->item_hook.'">'.$this->item_name.'</a></li>';

                        }

                    echo '
                        </ul>
                    ';

                break;
        }

    }
```

$this->menu_data from the secondary switch contains data of both $xml1 and $xml2. How can I prevent this?Unsetting $xml1 does not solve the problem.

The XML files look like this:

$xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<menu>

    <item>

        <name>Dashboard</name>
        <hook>/dashboard/view</hook>

    </item>

    <item>

        <name>Location</name>
        <hook>/location/list</hook>

    </item>

    <item>

        <name>Networks</name>
        <hook>/network/list</hook>

    </item>

    <item>

        <name>Devices</name>
        <hook>/device/list</hook>

    </item>

    <item>

        <name>Alarms &amp; Events</name>
        <hook>/alarm/list</hook>

    </item>

</menu>
```

$xml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<menu>

    <item>

        <name>Network List</name>
        <hook>/network/list</hook>

    </item>

    <item>

        <name>Add Network</name>
        <hook>/network/add</hook>

    </item>

</menu>
```

Could you please help me or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need the first `$` in call `$returnSimpleXmlObject($xml_path1)`

Comment: Sorry, it was an "copy & paste" mistake.

Comment: OK - when you say `$xml` contains both files - where do you set `$xml`?  I've tried (as far as I can) to reproduce and the two files seem to load properly ( although I had to change it to `return new SimpleXMLElement($xml_path, 0, TRUE);` - with a 0 instead of null).

Comment: Sorry, my head is not in the game. I meant $xml2 contains both data.

Comment: I used the example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php. There it is working with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `returnArrayOfXmlElements` you always seem to use `$this->variableName`, this can cause problems as it will retain data across method calls.

Unless you really need to retain this data, try removing the `$this->` from each of the variables...

```
public function returnArrayOfXmlElements(string $xml_path, string $element_key) {

        // Variables
        $simplexml_array    = (array)$this->returnSimpleXmlObject($xml_path);

        // Variables With Dependencies
        $xml_elements       = $this->simplexml_array[$element_key];

        $xml_elements_rectified = [];

        foreach ($xml_elements as $this->array_key => $this->array_value) {

            $xml_elements_rectified[] = (array)$this->array_value;

        }

        return $xml_elements_rectified;

    }
```